# How to allow customers to apply promo code on existing subscription in stripe customer portal?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal

in stripe customer portal settings I have set "Allow customers to apply promotion codes", but when I open customer portal I can't find anywhere, where I could add promo code.
I can cancel subscription, update payment methods or customer data as I configured in settings, but not promotion code. Is there something special that needs to be done?
In production we are opening that via special BillingPortalSession (stripe api), but I also checked with generated link from stripe it self.

billing portal configuration features looks like this:

```
"features": {
"customer_update": {
  "allowed_updates": [
    "email",
    "address",
    "phone"
  ],
  "enabled": true
},
"invoice_history": {
  "enabled": true
},
"payment_method_update": {
  "enabled": true
},
"subscription_cancel": {
  "cancellation_reason": {
    "enabled": true,
    "options": [
      "too_expensive",
      "missing_features",
      "switched_service",
      "unused",
      "other",
      "customer_service",
      "too_complex"
    ]
  },
  "enabled": true,
  "mode": "at_period_end",
  "proration_behavior": "none"
},
"subscription_pause": {
  "enabled": false
},
"subscription_update": {
  "default_allowed_updates": [
    "price",
    "promotion_code"
  ],
  "enabled": true,
  "proration_behavior": "create_prorations"
}
```

Comment: there is no problem with promotion code when creating checkout, only when trying to update existing subscription

Comment: Did you end up getting a solution for how to apply a promo code to an existing subscription without changing the plan/period?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the default portal configuration on your account, make sure to double check that your "Allow customers to apply promotion codes" setting is enabled in your dashboard settings[1].

If you are using the API to define your billing portal configuration, make sure to check that `promotion_code` is included in your portal's `features.subscription_update.default_allowed_updates` list[2].

If neither of those seem to work for you, you can get help by going to Stripe's Discord Server[3] or writing in to their support team[4]. If you go to one of those, please make sure to have an example request ID[5] from a time when you created a customer portal session and did not see the behavior that you were expecting.

---

[1] https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/billing/portal

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create#create_portal_configuration-features-subscription_update-default_allowed_updates

[3] https://stripe.com/go/developer-chat

[4] https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true

[5] https://stripe.com/docs/api/request_ids

Comment: I updated question with how features looks for portal configuration, but I guess it best to try support option.